# how to filter null values with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I do a request with RestSharp:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/timerecord", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<List<TimeRecordDTO>>(request);
```

The TimeRecords contains a Property SettledOn. This has a DateTime-Value or a null value:

```
...,"SettledOn":null,...
```

or

```
...,"SettledOn":"2018-01-02T18:26:01",...
```

Now I try to filter on this property. I want only the TimeRecords, where SettledOn is null.

I have tried this

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/timerecord", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("SettledOn", null);
var response = client.Execute<List<TimeRecordDTO>>(request);
```

But I get still all TimeRecords.

What do I have to do, to filter the Entities?

Comment: Does your api support that? if you code doesn't handle that you won't get the result. Though you can try sending it like this request.AddParameter("SettledOn", "null").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse the concepts here. RestSharp is just a HTTP client library. If your API method returns all TimeRecords entities, HTTP response will contain them all and RestSharp will deserialize whole list when you call `client.Execute<List<TimeRecordDTO>>(request);`.
Adding parameter `SettledOn` to the request does not affect anything until your API analyze this request parameter and perform actual filtering on server side.

So you have two options to filter the values:

**Client-side solution:**

Just filter entities with simple LINQ:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/timerecord", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<List<TimeRecordDTO>>(request);
var filtered = response.Data.Where(x => x.SettledOn == null);
```

**Server-side solution:**

You should adjust your API method implementation to analyze request parameter. If you need to add possibility to return only entities with `SettledOn` set to `null`, you could have request parameter `settledOnNullOnly`:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeRecordDTO> Get(bool settledOnNullOnly)
{
    //  Pass settledOnNullOnly to DB query or filter entities with LINQ
    //  ...
}
```

Now when you pass `settledOnNullOnly` set to `true`, you will receive only filtered entities.

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/values", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("settledOnNullOnly", "true");
var response = client.Execute<List<TimeRecordDTO>>(request);
```

Server-side solution is better from performance perspective, as you don't fetch and transfer unnecessary data. Use this approach if you have possibility to adjust the API and plan to use such filtering heavily. Otherwise client-side approach should work fine for you.